# Optimal package structure - Command Line Interface

Tags: python, repository

I have an ongoing project where the directory structure currently is a mess [(github Directory)](https://github.com/timoudas/premier_league_api/tree/master/API_scraper/model) and I would like to strucure it to eventully create a python package out of it. Below I have outlined a potential outline of the structure to package it and would like some feedback if below is a senceble way to do it on, or if there are things that should be considered. Input on how it can be structured in friendlier way or if things should be added/deleted would be highly appreciated.

```
cli_stats/      
|__ __init__.py 
|__ README.md   
|__ docs/   
|     |__ docs
|__ cli_stats/  
|     |__  cli_stats.py
|     |__  league_season_init.pickle (generated from setup.py)
|__ pickle/ 
|     |__  __init__.py
|     |__  setup.py
|     |__  get_id/
|     |       |__ __init__.py
|     |       |__ get_id.py
|     |__ get_stats/
|     |       |__ __init__.py
|     |       |__ get_stats.py
|     |__ api_scraper/
|         |__ __init__.py
|         |__ api_scraper.py
|         |__  check_api.py
|       
|__ directory/  
|    |__ __init__.py
|    |__ directory.py
|__clean_stats/ 
     |__ __init__.py
     |__ clean_stats.py
```

The dependenceis is the following, the order they att presented in represents on how they build on top of each other:

(The import statements represent the dependencies between modules in the current flat heirarcy which is flat)

#### api_scraper.py

This is the "main" module that handles the request to the API. It's the building block on which to `get_id.py` and `get_stats` is build upon.

#### get_id.py

```py
imports:

from api_scraper import Football
from directory import Directory
from directory import StorageConfig
```

This module retrieves Ids from the API and stores them in the in a folder named params/

#### get_stats.py

```py
imports:

from api_scraper import Football
from directory import Directory
from directory import StorageConfig
```

This module reads IDs from params/ and retreives stats from the API and stores them in a folder raw_data/

#### setup.py

```py
imports:

from get_stats import Stats
from get_stats import SeasonStats
from directory import Directory
from directory import StorageConfig
```

This module generates the league_season_init.pickle which is an essential file for cli_stats.py

#### clean_stats.py

```py
imports:

from directory import Directory
from directory import StorageConfig
```

This module cleans the data in raw_data/

#### directory.py

This module is a helper module for creating paths and to save/load/write json files, also holds the directory paths as variables in class

#### cli_stats.py

```py
imports:

from directory import Directory
from directory import StorageConfig
from get_stats import SeasonStats
import clean_stats as clean
```

This module is a Interactive Command Line interface that utilizes `clean_stats.py` and `get_stats.py`. Will be expanded to include more features as to push data from clean_data/ to a database.

Comment: I don't have enough experience in python to give an answer, but you might try to read [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) or try search google python style guide in github.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo Thank you for the input, before posting my questing I searched for info. But I could not find any good guide on how to structure repos hierarchy based on module dependencies, which is what I'm after.

Comment: Please take time reading that guide, when you find something I hope you answer your own question. Answer to this question might help me in the future.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo, certainly will read it, thank you!